# jquery plugin where an element stays on the page even while scrolling

Tags: jquery, plugins

I remember seeing this ecommerce site where the shopping cart followed you on the screen even when you scroll down the page.

Is there a plugin for that? what would it be called?

Comment: Yeah, the plugin is called CSS :P

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with only CSS by setting `position:fixed` but this is not supported in all browsers. If you need to support IE6 you can attach a handler to the scroll event and move the object based on the scroll.

Maybe something like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#idOfObject").css("top", $(window).scrollTop() + additionalOffset);
});
```

Or check out this for a full CSS solution which involves CSS Hacks (it isn't that bad) http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/